# Two webrtcbin's result in double the latency as oppose to just one

Tags: gstreamer

I'm curious if anyone knows why two webrtcbin's result in increased latency as oppose to when there is only one.

Setup One (~220 ms of latency)

```
                  -----> webrtcbin ->(video compositor)
webrtc endpoint 1                                      |                                            
                  <------------------------------------
```

Setup Two - Cross over of the RTP streams into each others audiomixer / video compositors (~500 ms)

```
webrtc endpoint 1 <----> webrtcbin(1)  (audiomixer/video compositor)
                                  \   /
                                   \ / 
                                   / \
                                  /   \
webrtc endpoint 2 <----> webrtcbin(2)  (audiomixer/video compositor)
```

I suspect it has something to do with the how GStreamer is handling multiple RTP streams and the clocks syncs involved. But that's just a hunch.

Additional information:

- both WebRTC endpoints are on the same machine
- both are sending audio and video
- GStreamer is using OPUS and H264
- GStreamer version is a little dated (1.18)
- Jitter Buffer value is 50
- Setup One does not have an audiomixer (as to not cause echo)